# Android override onDraw() issue

Tags: android, text, ondraw

I have a small issue here is the code i have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
        setContentView(new GraphicView(this));

        TextView mainLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
            mainLabel.setText("Android Circle Path");
    }

    static class GraphicView extends View{
        public GraphicView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){


        }
    }  
}
```

And the main.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="30dip"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip">

        <TextView
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:textSize="24.5sp"
            android:id="@+id/title">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When i try to set the text in the onDraw() function the app crashes, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The stack trace from logcat would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view's `onDraw` method should be used to render to that view alone. You should not be calling UI update methods in another view. Move the code for setting the title into your activity's `onCreate` method, since that only needs to be done once. Then just draw your circle in your custom view. Also, since your custom view does not implement ViewParent, it shouldn't be used to hold the title TextView. Reorganize your xml to move the title view outside the GraphicsView

Comment: so i moved the TextView out of the GraphicsView in my XML as well as moving the line of code to my onCreate method however it still crashes. Any other ideas?

Comment: Where is it crashing, and with what exception? Please edit your post and add the logcat for the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` is a local variable created in the `onCreate` method of that `Activity`. So the scope of `TextView` is confined within that `onCreate` method only. You can't access it outside that method. Moreover what you are trying to do is not the right way, inside `GraphView`'s `onDraw` method you are supposed to draw the `GraphView` components alone, not the outside views or anything else.